# Two rails models both with a habtm relationship to a third model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a question about has and belongs to many when it applies to multiple models.  I've seen a couple other similar questions about habtm with multiple models but none quite like this (they usually apply to two models, not three).

Suppose I have The following classes:

- Students
- Clubs
- Rooms

Students habtm Clubs--Students can join multiple Clubs and Clubs have multiple Students.

Rooms habtm Clubs--a Room may have multiple Clubs that use it and a Club may use multiple Rooms.

There is no direct relationship between Students and Rooms.

I don't see any issue with using two habtm relationships in the same class (the Club class), but there may be subtleties that I'm missing.

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :clubs
end

class Clubs < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :students
  has_and_belongs_to_many :rooms
end

class Rooms < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :clubs
end
```

I assume in such a case I can also use :through on one or both of the relationships.

1. Are there any known issues?
2. Is there some other pattern in Rails I should use instead that I'm not thinking of?

Comment: I don't think there is any issue at all with what you're doing. Having multiple (distinct) HABTM relationships in a single model is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've posted is the correct and optimal design for this.

There's no similarities between room and student so a polymorphic isnt suitable and the relationships are right.